# Italian Visa has wrong dates

Tags: visas, italy, student-visas

Received my Italian "D" type visa for language study. I arrive Feb 2 and leave Italy June 7. The visa was sent with the dates of Feb 3 thru June 5 which are the actual dates of the classes I will be taking. The application had all the correct dates requested and clearly spelled out. Anyone have this issue and any advice on resolving it?

Comment: Contact the consulate immediately. Do not wait even one minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting the Italian Consulate I was told that this is not a problem.  The study visa should only cover the days I will be taking classes. As Americans do not require a tourist visa there is no issue with entering Italy a day before and departing 2 days after classes are over.